# Find key and value in hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes:

```
b = [
  {
    id: 2,
    Sector: "Crops",
    2011-12: 17.6,
    2012-13: 18.9,
    2013-14: 14.2,
    2014-15: 13.1,
    2015-16: 12.3,
    2016-17: 12.1,
    created_at: "2018-08-27T06:11:29.000Z",
    updated_at: "2018-08-27T06:11:29.000Z"
  }
]
```

I am getting this array from my db.

I want to map the keys and the values of the hashes to get a new array like this:

```
[
  {
    y: 17.6,
    label: "2011-12"
  },
  {
    y:18.9,
    label: "2012-13",
    ...
  }
]
```

I am trying this code:

```
u = []
b.each do |col|
  u.push({y:25, label:"2011"})
  u.push({y:35, label:"2012"})
end
```

This generates a new array as I expected, but when I try to get key and value using:

```
b.each do |col|
  col.each do |key, value|
    puts "The hash key is #{key} and the value is #{value}."
  end
end
```

I get this error:

```
undefined method `each' for
```

What is wrong with this? How can I get the key and value of any hash and how to use that in my case ?

As I can see error is 2011-12: 17.6, 2011-12 should be string. But I am getting this value from db. How to resolve this issue if I want to create an array in my format.

So my problem is my column names are in 2012-13 and when I am running a query I am getting value as it is.

I am getting this when using b.inspect:

```
 #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<AnnualStateDomesticProduct3 id: 2, Sector: "Crops", 2011-12: 17.6, 2012-13: 18.9, 2013-14: 14.2, 2014-15: 13.1, 2015-16: 12.3, 2016-17: 12.1, created_at: "2018-08-27 06:11:29", updated_at: "2018-08-27 06:11:29">]>
```

My migrations for this table is:

```
def change
create_table :annual_state_domestic_product3s do |t|
  t.string :Sector
  t.float :'2011-12'
  t.float :'2012-13'
  t.float :'2013-14'
  t.float :'2014-15'
  t.float :'2015-16'
  t.float :'2016-17'

  t.timestamps
end
```

So my question is how to get value in string format ?

Comment: no my b array of hash is correct I am trying to create a new array into my new fromat. I am getting error for which I am trying.

Comment: ``undefined method `each' for`` – there seem to be missing something after `for`

Comment: I have just added the error. I have added one solution which I have tried I need answer to covert that array into a format which I am trying to get

Comment: BTW, `2011-12: 17.6` is invalid syntax – a (unquoted) key must not contain `-`. Please fix your example code, so that it is runnable (e.g. use `'2011-12': 17.6` or `'2011-12' => 17.6`). Otherwise it might seem as if the problem is due to a syntax error.

Comment: Can you try to convert the result of your query to json? Check https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Result.html

Comment: Apparently `b` is an `ActiveRecord::Relation` instance, not an array. This means that `b.each` doesn't return hashes, but `ActiveRecord` instances, in your case `AnnualStateDomesticProduct3` instances.

Comment: Any solution for my question

Comment: b.all.each do |col|
  col.each do |key, value|
    puts "The hash key is #{key} and the value is #{value}."
  end
end

Comment: Getting same error undefined each method

Comment: Check if the edit to my answer can help solve your problem about the correct hash: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52036370/5239030

Answer (score 0):

as hermanvicente says, 2011-12 is not a valid hash key (it's an expression). Must be quoted as a string.

```
b = [
  {
    id: 2,
    "Sector": "Crops",
    "2011-12": 17.6,
    "2012-13": 18.9,
    "2013-14": 14.2
  }
]

b.each do |col|
  col.each do |key, value|
    puts "The hash key is #{key} and the value is #{value}."
  end
end
```

prints

```
The hash key is id and the value is 2.
The hash key is Sector and the value is Crops.
The hash key is 2011-12 and the value is 17.6.
The hash key is 2012-13 and the value is 18.9.
The hash key is 2013-14 and the value is 14.2.
```

Comment: Peter I am getting that value from my db where 2011-12 is my column name how to convert symbol into string.

Comment: How exactly are you generating the "b= ... "  statement? Using Ruby or some other tool?

Comment: I am getting that value using model.where('Sector = ? ', rain_fall_type).order('id')

Comment: OK you are using Rails then.  I would suggest outputting the "b" variable using b.inspect. That way you can see it completely. Paste the output here pls.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: really interesting! What is the datatype of the table column? Are you using MySQL or Sqlite?

Comment: I am using mysql and data type is float for 2011-12

Comment: I think your problem would go away if you renamed the column to "X2011-12" (or whatever syntax you choose as long as it doesnt start with a number). However I can't find any proof for this. It's just a hunch.

Comment: OK I see an error now in your question, b since b is a Relation, it's not an array. You must call .all or .first to get the table row.

Comment: @PeterAndersson being an ORM, ActiveRecord doesn't return raw table rows, it returns objects.

Comment: I thought that was what I said. This is Rails excellent Lazy Loading technique.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following hash (not the array, note the quotes wrapping the keys, as pointed).

```
h = {
      id: 2,
      Sector: "Crops",
      "2011-12": 17.6,
      "2012-13": 18.9,
      "2013-14": 14.2,
      "2014-15": 13.1,
      "2015-16": 12.3,
      "2016-17": 12.1,
      created_at: "2018-08-27T06:11:29.000Z",
      updated_at: "2018-08-27T06:11:29.000Z"
    }
```

This is one way you can get the required result.

```
h.delete_if { |k,v| [:id, :Sector, :created_at, :updated_at].include? k }
.each_with_object([]) { |pair, ary| ary << { y: pair.last, label: pair.first } }

# => [{:y=>17.6, :label=>:"2011-12"}, {:y=>18.9, :label=>:"2012-13"}, ... ]
```

Maybe you need to change the array of keys to delete into `['id', 'Sector', 'created_at', 'updated_at']`

If you have an array of hashes (your `b` variable), map each element with the coded provided:

```
result = array_of_hashes.map do |h|
  h.delete_if { |k,v| [:id, :Sector, :created_at, :updated_at].include? k }
  .each_with_object([]) { |pair, ary| ary << { y: pair.last, label: pair.first } }
end
```

### EDIT - Getting the correct array of hashes from database

This is one possible solution, since the column names are not standard, and the returned object from the database looks like this:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<AnnualStateDomesticProduct3 id: 2, Sector: "Crops", 2011-12: 17.6, 2012-13: 18.9, 2013-14: 14.2, 2014-15: 13.1, 2015-16: 12.3, 2016-17: 12.1, created_at: "2018-08-27 06:11:29", updated_at: "2018-08-27 06:11:29">]>
```

One workaround is to convert to JSON and then parse into a hash, as already pointed in one comment:

```
b = JSON.parse(AnnualStateDomesticProduct.all.to_json)
```

Also, to get attribute value from an object you can "call the column" like this:

```
a = AnnualStateDomesticProduct.find(2)
a.send('2011-12') # => 17.6
```

Comment: It is an array of hashes and not a single hash.